# No puedo crear una variable vacia

Tags: php

//Creo la variable array session

```
session_start();
$fact = [0 => 0];
$_SESSION['facturacion'] = $fact;
```

// La recogo en otro archivo

```
include 'cn.php';
session_start();
$fact = $_SESSION['facturacion'];

$total = 0;
if(isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['c']))
{
 $id = $_POST['e'];
 $cantidad = $_POST['c'];

 if(count($_SESSION['facturacion']) <= 8){
 for ($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['facturacion']); $i++) { 
 if (!(in_array($id, $fact))) {
  $resultado1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE ID = 
  $id") or die();
  $fila1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado1);
  if ($fila1['ProductS'] >= $cantidad) {
    $fact[$id] = $cantidad;
    $_SESSION['facturacion'] = $fact;


   }

   }
   } 
 }


 }

 $precio = 1;

foreach ($fact as $key => $value) {
$resultado = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE ID = $key") 
or die();
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
$precio = $fila['ProductP'];
$total+=$value*$precio;

if ($key != 0) {
$Subtotal = $precio*$value;
$p = strpos($precio, ".");
if($p === false){$Subtotal = $Subtotal.".00";}else{$Subtotal = 
$Subtotal."0";}
$salida.= "
          <tr>
            <td>".$value."</td>
            <td>".$fila['ProductU']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['ProductN']."</td>
            <td>".$fila['ProductP']."</td>
            <td>".$Subtotal."<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></td>
          </tr>";

  } 
 }
 echo $salida;
 mysqli_close($link);
```

Quiero crear la variable en el segundo archivo, pero cuando lo intento no puedo, y no puedo dejar de usar [0 => 0]; porque me sale error, mi pregunta es **Como creo el array en el segundo archivo y guardar ese array en $_SESSION**

Comment: No despliega ningun error, el problema inicia cuando quiero crear el session array en el segundo archivo y no el primer archivo (que es lo que necesito) `$fact = array();
$_SESSION['facturacion'] = $fact;`

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: facturacion in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\php\order.php on line 25

Comment: ´if(count($_SESSION['facturacion']) <= 8){´ No habia definido el session, ya lo definí, pero no me funciona foreach

Comment: Si haces un `print_r($fact)` antes del foreach que te despliega?

Comment: Array ( ) Literal

Comment: si pongo `$fact = array(0 => 0)` funciona, pero no quiero ese elemento en mi array

Comment: Obviamente, si el arreglo está vacío nunca entrará en el bucle `for` por lo tanto no se llena `$fact`, al poner `$fact = array(0 => 0)` tiene un elemento y entra en el bucle llenando el array `$fact`

Comment: Si quieres que tenga un número de vueltas podrías intentar hacer `$i=0; $i < $max; $i++` donde `$max` es el número de vueltas que necesitas

Comment: Tengo otro error, el foreach solo se ejecuta 1 sola vez

Comment: y el for que es para añadir nuevos valores al array funciona, lo comprobe con varios echo ""; pero no añade el nuevo valor al array sino que lo remplaza por el existente

Answer (score 1):

Con esto...

```
if (!(in_array($id, $fact))) {
```

...estás buscando `$id` en el array `$fact`, pero resulta que en $fact lo que estás poniendo son cantidades y el valor `$id` lo usas de clave:

```
$fact[$id] = $cantidad;
```

La búsqueda de `$id` la tendrías que hacer sobre las claves de `$fact`:

```
if (!(in_array($id, array_keys($fact)))) {
```

O mejor:

```
if (!isset($fact[$id})) {
```